# php split string

Tags: php

in php I want to split the following value by using @$

```
$val = "test1@$test";
```

But using explode it can't.any solutions?

Comment: why isn't explode working? what was the error? can you post your code?

Comment: learn the difference between single and double quotes and these types of things won't happen as often (people still make mistakes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will if you escape the `$` sign in double quotes. Or alternatively use single quotes to express the string.

**Example:**

`$val = "test1@\$test";`

or

`$val = 'test1@$test';`

If a dollar sign ($) is encountered, the parser will greedily take as many tokens as possible to form a valid variable name according to [the manua](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)l.

Answer (score 0):

It *is* possible to explode to do this:

```
$val = 'test1@$test';
$array = explode('@$', $val);
print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$val = "test1@$test";
var_dump($val); // string(6) "test1@"
```

It's not the `split()` that's failing -- it's the assignment statement.